# Unicode file I/O with Javascript and gjs?

Tags: unicode, gnome, gnome-3, gio, gjs

Can anybody give any working example of how to read/write **Unicode** text files using **Javascript** and  [**Gjs**](https://live.gnome.org/Gjs/), possibly using Gio and/or Glib? I'm experienced in Javascript, but these APIs are still alien to me and being quite new technologies, googling is not helping much.

I've seen this one: https://live.gnome.org/Seed/Tutorial/Simple_file_io , but it is Seed based (not Gjs), and seems quite old. I'm getting errors (like too few arguments on Gio.read on line 9) and thus cannot test using Unicode text.

A working snippet will be much helpful. Thanks!

**Update**: I'm testing on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: It might be useful to add a snippet of the code you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a general idea, you can check the example [gio-cat.js](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gjs/tree/examples/gio-cat.js) from [gjs source code repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gjs/tree).

You might also check the answer for "[How to start writing Gnome Shell extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305423/278878)", which has some links that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind reading the text file synchronously, you can use GLib's helper function [GLib.file_get_contents(String fileName)](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/GLib-2.0/GLib.file_get_contents.html):

```
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;
//...
let fileContents = String(GLib.file_get_contents("/path/to/yourFile")[1]);
```